# Android ListView doesn't receive itemClick events after removed with removeAllViews() and restored with addView

Tags: android, events, listview, onitemclicklistener, viewstack

I implemented a View stack system for my Android application, which, upon pushing a new View removes the current view in the target layout, stores it in the stack and then adds the new View to the layout.

It works flawlessly until I try storing and then restoring a View containing a ListView. When doing so, the ListView receives no itemClick events, although it does scroll.

The code for the stack system is as follows:

```
Stack<View> viewStack;

public View pushView(View v) {
    // 1. Get reference to main content panel
    LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contentPanel);
    View last = content.getChildAt(0);
    // Pushing old to stack
    viewStack.push(last);

    // 2. Clear it
    content.removeAllViews();

    // 3. Add new View
    content.addView(v);

    return last;
}

public View popView() {
    if (!viewStack.isEmpty()) {
        // 1. Get reference to main content panel
        LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contentPanel);
        View last = content.getChildAt(0);

        // 2. Clear it
        content.removeAllViews();

        // 3. Add last View
        content.addView(viewStack.pop());
        // Pushing old to stack
        return last;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Curiously, the other items in the View that contains the ListView (CheckBoxes and a Button) DO receive clickEvents. 
I suspect:
1. The ListView has lost focus so it won't receive those events, or
2. The ListView has been detached of the onItemClickListener

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you have to add the listener on each item when you add it to the view

Comment: Of course, when the View containing the ListView is built and added for the first time, everything is working. The problem arises when stored and restored with the methods shown. I'm sorry I forgot to point that :)

Comment: Okay, you add the listener the first time but not after ?

Comment: No, not after adding it again, I was expecting to avoid that. What made me think about it was that regular buttons in the same View mantain their listeners when restored. If listeners must be re-added for the ListView, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have set "clickable" as "true" in you layout in xml file then remove it from every where. then you can try...

If you are declaring anywhere then only. If you are declaring "view_name.setClickable(true)" then remove this line. One more thing if you are using ontouchlistener then always return false. Actually i have faced similar problem in which I was using listview and imageview in listview row. My imageview was receiving click event but listview was not receiving onitemclick event because i had set imageview as clickable in my layout.

Comment: There is nothing with clickable as true in the container layout nor the added layout. Should I explicitly declare clickable as 'false' to components?

Comment: No if you are declaring anywhere then only.